# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget (No stacktrace)

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-alertdialog

I have the following layout for an alert dialog:

```
AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Some Text'),
        content: StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: usersWithoutBirthdays.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return CheckboxListTile(
                          title: Text("More Text Here"),
                          value: someValue,
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                            if (value != null) {
                              setState(() {
                                //Set state logic here
                              });
                            }
                          }
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text("Cancel"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                            child: Text("Continue"),
                            onPressed:
                            //OnPressed logic here
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                ],
              )
            );
          }
        )
    );
```

In the console all I see is:

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════ Incorrect use
> of ParentDataWidget.

This happens every time I scroll down within the alert when it is shown.

I have looked at similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63500318/incorrect-use-of-parentdatawidget-flutter), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987207/flutter-incorrect-use-of-parentdatawidget)) and have tried the following solutions:

- Wrapping the Container within a column and the ListView inside of an Expanded widget
- Just wrapping the ListView within an Expanded widget

As you can see, there is no Expanded widget as part of the ListView's layout and since the stacktrace is not informative, I don't understand where the problem lies.

Should I have laid out the alert dialog differently? What I set to accomplish is have a layout that is scrollable and has a list of checkboxes the user can mark.

***Ignoring this error, all the functionality works and there is no other issue.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Spacer Widget from your code. Try below code hope its help to you.

bool variable for test ***checked*** and ***unchecked*** **`CheckBox`**

```
  bool someValue = false;
```

Your Widget:

```
  ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // write your onPressed function here
          alertDialog();
          print('Button Pressed');
        },
        child: const Text('Press Me'),
      ),
```

Your alertDialog method:

```
alertDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Some Text'),
          content: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: 30,//usersWithoutBirthdays.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text("More Text Here"),
                            value: someValue,
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              if (value != null) {
                                setState(() {
                                  //Set state logic here
                                });
                              }
                            });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: Text("Continue"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  //OnPressed logic here
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

You can test your code [`Dartpad`](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id)

Comment: Can you explain why the Spacer widget was causing the error?

Comment: @tomerpacific I think if you used `Spacer` inside `Column` it does work sometime Spacer takes the your wanted space in that

Comment: But why was having a Spacer element generating the exception regarding the ParentDataWidget? I know what the Spacer widget does.